# In Stored Procedure having error using 'and' after using where-between-parameter

Tags: sql-server, join

here is the query

```
SET @SQL = '
SELECT name AS BUYER, OrderQty, OrderQty* Rate as Value
FROM
OrderMaster OM
INNER JOIN LineAllocation LA ON LA.OrderRef= OM.OrderRefID
INNER JOIN SystemManager..Contacts SC ON SC.Code=OM.BuyerCode
INNER JOIN SystemManager..ProductionProcessCostCenter PPC ON PPC.CostCenter= LA.Line
INNER JOIN OrderMasterCostBreakdown OCB ON OCB.OrderRefID= OM.OrderRefID
INNER JOIN SystemManager..ProductionProcess PP ON PP.ProcessID = PPC.ProcessId

where  (UseDate BETWEEN '''+Cast(@FromDate As Varchar)+''' and '''+Cast(@ToDate As Varchar)+''') AND Process='Sewing'
'
```

Comment: ERROR message is "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spRPTMonthlyProductionSummaryFORATL, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near 'Sewing'."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
AND Process=''Sewing'''
```

instead of

```
AND Process='Sewing' '
```